# Use if with iloc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to use conditional if with a value extracted of a `DataFrame` with `iloc`?
Something like this:

```
if dta.iloc[[1],[5]] == "Example":
    print("Ok")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: But it seems need `if (dta.iloc[[1],[5]]=="Example").any():`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, need remove nested `[]` for scalar:

```
dta.iloc[1,5]
```

**Sample**:

```
dta = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (dta)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

print (dta.iloc[1,5])
a

if dta.iloc[1,5]=="a":
    print("Ok")

Ok
```

---

But if `iloc` return `Series` add [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check if exist at least one `True`:

```
print (dta.iloc[1:4,5])
1    a
2    a
3    b
Name: F, dtype: object

print (dta.iloc[1:4,5] == 'a')
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: F, dtype: bool

print ((dta.iloc[1:4,5] == 'a').any())
True
```

And for `DataFrame` simpliest is use [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) for check at least one `True` in `2d array`:

```
print (dta.iloc[1:4,4:6])
   E  F
1  3  a
2  6  a
3  9  b

print (dta.iloc[1:4,4:6] == 'a')
       E      F
1  False   True
2  False   True
3  False  False

print ((dta.iloc[1:4,4:6] == 'a').values.any())
True
```

Comment: @GerardBoxóCorominas, There's no need to apologize for the question. BUT what you *should* do is go back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51944340/edit) so that it is more precise/useful for the wider community, e.g. with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use **values**.

In your example:

`if dta.iloc[[1],[5]].values=="Example":
    print("Ok")`